# HTML Required Field Validation Issues

Tags: html

I have a small HTML form created that has a required input field; when I hover the mouse over the field, it shows the message "Please fill in this field" but when I click the button to submit, the error message does not display.

Here is the section of code containing the input field and button:

```
    Web Word Count App
</div>
<div>

    <textarea id="paragraph" rows="5" cols="35" placeholder="Enter the paragraph here..." value="" required="true" >Enter the paragraph here...
    </textarea>
</div>
    <div>
    <input  type="text" id="word"  placeholder="Enter the keyword here..." value="" required="true" >
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="display" id="display-1" readonly=1 placeholder="Total word count = 0 " value=""><br>
    <input type="text" class="display" id="display-2" readonly=1 placeholder="Keyword does not exist!" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" class="display" id="display-3" readonly=1 placeholder="Total keyword appearances = 0" value="">
</div>
<div>
    <button class="wwcbutton" onclick="Word_count();">Total words?</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="wwcbutton" onclick="Check();">Check keyword appearance</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button  class="wwcbutton" onclick="keyword_count();">Total keyword appearances?</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="wwcbutton-clear" onclick="Clear();">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Could someone please advise me as to what might be wrong here. Thanks

Comment: Which button are you clicking to submit? If you want browsers to prevent submission processing with an incomplete form you can use `<input type="submit".../>`.